# Firebase Login - How to reset uid?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Ionic2 rc4, and Firebase Authentication. If I call `signupFirebaseUser()`, it logs a `uid` as expected. However, when I then call `loginGoogle()`, I would expect it to log a different `uid`, but it prints the same `uid`.

This means that a user cannot log in with an `email address` and `password`, log out, and then re log in with their Google account (different email address) because it wants to retain their old `uid`.

```
signupFirebaseUser(email: string, password: string): firebase.Promise<any> {
    return this.fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((newUser: firebase.User) => {
        console.log(newUser.uid);
        this.userProfile.child(newUser.uid).set({ email: email });
        newUser.sendEmailVerification();
    });
}
```

then

```
public logout(auth: FirebaseAuth, fireAuth: firebase.auth.Auth): Promise<any> {
        return auth.logout().then(() => {
            fireAuth.signOut().then(() => {
            });
        });
}
```

then

```
  loginGoogle() {
    this.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Google,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    }).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        console.log(data.uid);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('loginGoogle', error);
    });
  }
```

**Question**

How do you reset the Firebase Authentication to forget the old `uid`? So that when you log in again, you do so from a clean start.

i.e. Generate a new `uid` for each provider (Google, Facebook, Email).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: One way could be deleting the user using user.delete() and then recreating it will automatically have a new UID

Comment: Yes, you are right that will work. But what happens if you want to re-login as the old user again (i.e. keep swapping users)? I don't want to delete the account because I store data against each user.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the issue. Could you try using the new Firebase Auth API for Google Sign-in? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin). If you need Cordova support you can use an OAuth plugin (e.g. https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth) and then call signInWithCredential() with the returned access token.

Comment: Surely changing from AngularFire2 to the ng-cordova-oauth api won't make any difference? Aren't they both just calling the same Firebase api?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the option on which ensures you can only have one account per email address (this is actually the default if I remember correctly). To change this option, head to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers, select your Firebase project, scroll down to "Advanced" section, and hit the "Change" button next to "One account per email address." There you can set how to handle accounts for the same email address and turn off this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me. I do only want one account for each email address, but I want more than one email address to be able to sign in on the same devise or browser. My problem is if a different email address tries to sign in, it fails because the uid does not change. All I want is a one to one mapping between email address and uid (or account).

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting when the sign in happens?

Comment: I am very confused now. It seems to be working when I test it. I must have had a bug in my code that I inadvertently fixed. Sorry for wasting your time. I appreciate the help.